# Cosmos DB Trigger Azure Function misses some change feed

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, cosmosdbtrigger

We've implemented a service with multiple Azure Functions in it. An HttpTrigger function will insert records into Cosmos DB. Then the Cosmos DB Trigger function will process the records when it's fired. Some times the jobs for the DB trigger function could take quite some time. If new records inserted into the Cosmos DB while the DB Trigger function is running with previous job, the new records would not cause the event to be triggered.

How we can prevent this from happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause of the problem: we were not looping through the change feed. Instead we were only processing the first item from the input of the trigger.